# how to use lanczos code from netlib for large sparse symmetric matrix?

Tags: eigensystem, fortran, lapack, banded-matrix

I want to use lanczos method to calculate the few lowest eigenvalue and eigen-vector of a large sparse symmetric matrix(~50k x ~50k). In http://www.netlib.org/lanczos/index.html I found the codes leval and levec are suitable for my situation. However, the instruction is too complicated to find how to use it and I don't know how to set the input and output files.
Who used it and please gives some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: @lagerbaer i am using fortran90...

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question, but maybe you want to use something like ARPACK, for example [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) in python.

Comment: I want help in terms of fortran only thanks @k20

Comment: Although k20 referred to a python interface to ARPACK, the underlying ARPACK software *is* written in FORTRAN. And it is very well documented. http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/